# Jquery elements follow each other

Tags: html, jquery-animate

I have been working on this. Obviously, it uses key binding to animate and shoot bullets. Unfortunately, if you move up or down and a bullet is on its way to the target, and you move up or down, the bullet moves with you. Same situation with the target. So I looked at css positioning, and I think that the problem could be that somehow the created bullet is appended to the player. I have tried to change the positioning on both of them, and changing the bullet creater code to append to body. To no avail.

Here is my link:http://jsfiddle.net/5khhmepv/9/

And here is the creator code that I think is the problem:

```
var shoot = function () {
    if (canshoot === true) {
        canshoot = false;
        bullety = 0;
        var div = $('<div class=' + 'bullet' + ' style=' + 'marginTop:-25;' + '>yt</div>');
        div.appendTo('html');
        div.animate({
            marginLeft: 500 + 'px'
        }, 1500);
        canshoot = false;
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(".bullet").hide();
            canshoot = true;
        }, 1500);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By setting the position of your `#player` element to `static`, you make the size of the document dependent on how far down the document your player is. Moving your player up and down then causes the bullet to shift based on its relationship to the document height. What you probably want to do is have a fixed-size canvas, and absolutely positioned `#player` and `.bullet`. Don't forget to initialize the bullet's `top` to be aligned with the player's current scrollOffset.

Comment: That works! All I had to do was set the position to absolute and then make a few more changes!

Comment: How would I check for collision between player and bullet?

Answer (score 0):

I made some quick adjustments to your fiddle and i think it's working as intended.

http://jsfiddle.net/5khhmepv/28/

Basically you shouldn't use `static` as position value as Palpatim explained.

Comment: This is probably going to be another question, but is the up/down movement bugged for you? After moving one direction, when I push the opposite direction, the #player moves the wrong the first step, then moves the correct direction after that.

Comment: Yup. I fixed it though: http://jsfiddle.net/5khhmepv/27/ All that I needed to do was take y-=10; and put it at the top, so it calculates y before it animates. Thanks for bringing it to my attention!